# Rails: accessing records where two conditions are met

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, where-clause

I'm trying to access the number of "customer" records that were created today.  Something along the lines of:

```
@customersToday = User.where("created_at >= ?", Date.today,  user_type: 'Customer').count
```

How can I do this in a single query (that works)?

Comment: How is this not already a single query?

Comment: That is a single query. Perhaps rephrase your question?

Comment: The query in my question doesn't work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
@customersToday = User.where("created_at >= ? and user_type = ?", Date.today, 'Customer').count
```

Answer (score 0):

Yours should run in a single query, but you can simplify it by creating a couple of scopes

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  scope :today, -> { where ["created_at >= ?", Date.today] }
  scope :customers, -> { where user_type: 'Customer' }
end
```

Now you can run

```
User.customers.today.count
```

Comment: This gave me a no method error.  Tried both User.customer.today.count and User.customers.today.count